# set alert on this library disabled for some users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have shared files to the external clients who has an outlook account. I have tried to set alert using his profile but the set alert on this library disabled.
We are using sharePoint online. please see the image below.

[image]

is there any way that i can make the users set alert by themselfs?

Comment: Was this migrated from a previous version of SharePoint or was it built in your current environment?

Comment: it is not migrated. we created this library

Answer (score 0):

By providing the external users access to your SharePoint Online sites you can set up alerts for them and they can set up alerts with themselves , So Make sure that the External Sharing  is configured properly as [Office 365 Admin center](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/ultimate-guide-deal-with-office-365-external-sharing#configureExternalSharing) . For more details check [SharePoint External Users and Alerts](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-external-users-and-alerts/640afe76-2aab-4699-a001-6480cfd25c13)

If the `Alert ME` is still disabled , make sure that you have already shared this library to these external users .

If you need to set alert for a specific folder in your library, the alert me option is disabled , try the following

- Try to `View properties` for this folder.

[image]

- From the above ribbon click on `Alert me` and set the external users email.

[image]

Comment: hi M.Qassas, Alert is enabled and user has rights to it, I can set alert for myself but when the external user tried it in his the alert is disabled. I may be able to do it for him as an intern measure. but ideally user's should be able to do it by themselfs